# Can a carbon fiber mountain bike handle cool/cold weather?

Tags: mountain-bike, winter, carbon, weather

It is late summer in the US and I am starting to look forward to autumn and winter mountain biking. I have a carbon fiber frame though. Didn't get to ride it last winter due to a broken collar bone (almost landed that jump). So, anything to be concerned about riding a carbon fiber mountain bike in cool/cold weather? I am talking anything from 50°F/10°C down to sub freezing temps.

Comment: The fiber itself can probably handle temps down to near absolute zero.  The resins used to bond the fibers will get stiffer with cold, but should be good to 40 below or so.  Just getting down to freezing ain't cold at all.  After all, they make Shuttle wing parts out of carbon fiber.

Comment: I hardly believe that bike parts would be tested to the same tolerances as shuttle wings.  Just because it's the same material, doesn't mean it can withstand the same stresses. That doesn't mean it won't withstand it, but just stating that the logic isn't valid.

Answer (score 9):

Did a quick look around... And Zinn in Velonews gets questions like this. Short answer is: no problem. Essentially carbon fiber is a pretty tough material and barring manufacturing flaws should put up with a lot.

Comment: and my "no" is to your question "So, anything to be concerned about riding a carbon fiber mountain bike in cool/cold weather?" - as I just realized I'm saying the opposite based on the topic header.

Comment: I clarified this answer as it's ambiguous and it didn't look like the OP was coming back to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Many fatbike manufacturers are currently making full carbon frames intended to be raced and ridden at sub zero temperatures.  These manufacturers were previously using titanium, but most folks ran all the same carbon parts that everyone else did on their regular mountain bikes.  Short answer, yes.  This has been done for a long time and the breakage rate hasn't been anything different than normally seen with warm weather riding.

Comment: The advantage is if you lick a carbon frame, your tongue won't stick to it. The disadvantage is if you date your buddy to lick a cf frame, it's no fun.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using carbon handlebars on my mtb for two years now with any issue.  Even did a race that was so cold that my drink tube froze before I even started!